# How to create generic type instance in and use property a method

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose I have two classes: Student and Teacher.
I want to make a generic method that will return a list of one of the two classes, based on the type passed as a parameter.

```
class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BloodGroup { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; } 
}

class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BloodGroup { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

class GenericClassTest
{
    public List<T> getInformation<T>(List<T> infos )
    {
        var infoList = new List<T>(); // It's not working
        foreach (T item in infos)
        {
            T info = new T();
            info.Id = item.Id;
            info.Name = item.Name;
            info.BloodGroup = item.BloodGroup;
            info.Address = item.Address;
            infoList.Add(info);
        }
        return infoList;
    }
}
```

How can I instantiate ***T*** that should represent both Student and Teacher classes. I want to be able to do the following calls:

```
getInformation<Student>(studentList);
getInformation<Teacher>(teacherList);
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, make both Teacher and Student inherit from the same parent class?

Comment: Well. It will work after making a parent class.
However, is it possible without making parent class or other class?

Comment: Without an interface - `dynamic`. Not recommended.

Comment: As mentioned above, without a parent class or an interface, it can be done by using List<object> or List<dynamic>, but why would you? these are obviously related objects.

Answer (score 3):

I would add a parent class that Student and Teacher both inherit from. Then, you can limit the generic parameter on your method to be of that parent type. You probably have some more work to do in your getInformation() method, but this should get you going:

```
class Person
{   
    public Person()
    {

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BloodGroup { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

class Student : Person
{
    //unique Student properties go here
}
class Teacher : Person
{
    //unique teacher properties go here
}

class GenericClassTest
{
    public List<T> getInformation<T>(List<T> infos )
        where T : Person, new()
    {
        var infoList = new List<T>(); // It's not working
        foreach (T item in infos)
        {
            T info = new T();
            info.Id = item.Id;
            info.Name = item.Name;
            info.BloodGroup = item.BloodGroup;
            info.Address = item.Address;
            infoList.Add(info);
        }
        return infoList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for a [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface). An interface will allow you to access your methods and properties on your identical classes without knowing which one it is.

```
public interface ICantThinkOfAGoodName
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string BloodGroup { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; } 
}
```

You can then call your method like so:

```
getInformation<ICantThinkOfAGoodName>(studentList);
```

However, I would recommend removing your generic class you created, and just use List instead. You can look at objects, and edit them without knowing if the object is a student or teacher.